# Rounding JSON output

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Working on returning a value that is coming in from JSON as a long decimal. I need to convert it into a percentage, with only two trailing decimals.

With the code below, I've returned the value after multiplying it by 100 (to create the percent). But I'm having trouble rounding it to two decimal places.

Working code without rounding:

`' + localresults.races.slug1.candidates[0].pct *100 + '`

Code where I tried rounding but it didn't do anything (meaning, did not result in an error or deliver the intended result):

`' + localresults.races.slug1.candidates[0].pct * 100 toFixed(2) + '`

The raw data coming in for this example is `0.14285714285714285`. I want it to read `14.29` once it works through jQuery and is displayed.

I'm working with the latest version of jQuery and validated JSON.

Comment: You should wrap the multiplication in parentheses before calling toFixed(): `(localresults.races.slug1.candidates[0].pct * 100).toFixed(2)`

Comment: That worked! Thanks!